# Loop that determines how many days and weeks there are after a user gives an input

Tags: c

The code works as intended, but my issue is that I'd like for it to not print the statement `"0 days amounts to: 0 weeks, 0 days."`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int days;
    while (days >= 1) {
        printf("*** Days to Weeks Program ***\n"
               "Enter the number of days (or 0 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &days);
        int days_rem, weeks;
        int const days_per_week = 7;
        weeks = days / days_per_week;
        days_rem = days % days_per_week;
        printf("%d days amounts to: %d weeks, %d days.\n", days, weeks,
               days_rem);
    }
    printf("Thank you for playing!");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying not to use an `if` statement. I'm using only the info within the code.

Comment: When is the condition in the while loop while( days >= 1){ evaluated to true?

Comment: You may be interested in [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165)

Comment: `while(scanf("%d", &days) == 1 && days > 0)` and reposition the prompt.

Comment: "_[to] not to use an if_"... `printf( !days ? "" : "%d days amo...\n", ...);` Then use the ternary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this sequence, you declare a variable but you do not initialize it:

```c
int days;
while (days >= 1) {      
    scanf("%d", &days);
```

When you read the value of `days` in the `while` loop, `days` has an indeterminate value and using such values makes your program unpredictable. You should *first* assign a value to `days` before you check what the value is.

> I'd like for it to not print the statement `"0 days amounts to: 0 weeks, 0 days."` ... trying not to use an if statement

You then need to make that part of the loop condition.

To make it simple, I suggest breaking out the user input part and putting that in a function of its own.

It could look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int ask_for_days() {
    printf("*** Days to Weeks Program ***\n"
           "Enter the number of days (or 0 to quit): ");

    int days;

    // return 0 if input fails using the conditional operator ?:
    return scanf("%d", &days) == 1 ? days : 0;
}

int main() {
    for (int days; (days = ask_for_days()) > 0;) {
        int days_rem, weeks;
        int const days_per_week = 7;
        weeks = days / days_per_week;
        days_rem = days % days_per_week;
        printf("%d days amounts to: %d weeks, %d days.\n", days, weeks, days_rem);
    }
    printf("Thank you for playing!");
}
```

Comment: Using `days` does not give the program undefined behavior because its address is taken. It is merely an indeterminate value.

Comment: Hey thank you for taking the time to answer I was in a time crunch this is apart of a assignment for school where we are still learning the basics of C and while your answer was more advanced than where we are right now it did help a ton so thank you again

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm trying to find out how it works by reading the C23 draft. _J.2 Undefined behavior_, 1. "The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:" (11) _"The value of an object with automatic storage duration is **used** while the object has an indeterminate representation (6.2.4, 6.7.10, 6.8)."_ - Doesn't that mean that reading `days` makes it have UB?

Comment: @Jschaffer Glad to hear it helped! You're welcome!

Comment: Annex J is informative (that is in its title) and has errors. It is not a normative part of the document, the parts that actually constitute the C standard. The controlling clause is 6.3.2 2: “… If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the `register` storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah... thanks! I reworded it a bit.